Reload ajax datatable in rails
im using rails 7 with server-side ajax datatable. When delete a row and call reload(), it doesn't reload datatable. It used to work with rails 6.
When I click on delete button, it deletes de data row normally, and ajax return success, but when call reload(), nothing happens. If I refresh the page, the deleted row don't appear anymore as expected.
Any ideas?
I'm using datatable from cdn:
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/bs5/jq-3.7.0/jszip-3.10.1/dt-2.0.8/b-3.0.2/b-html5-3.0.2/fh-4.0.1/r-3.0.2/rg-1.5.0/sc-2.4.3/sb-1.7.1/sp-2.3.1/sl-2.0.3/datatables.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.2.7/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.2.7/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/bs5/jq-3.7.0/jszip-3.10.1/dt-2.0.8/b-3.0.2/b-html5-3.0.2/fh-4.0.1/r-3.0.2/sc-2.4.3/datatables.min.js"></script>

I delete the datatable if not null because it wasn't rendering the datatable
Here's my full script
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {
    
    // Initialize DataTable
    var table = $('#datatable').DataTable({
        processing: true,
        serverSide: true,
        ajax: {
            url: "/admin/softwares.json",
            type: "GET",
            dataSrc: function(json) {
                return json.data;
            }
        },
        columns: [
            { 
                data: 'id', 
                orderable: false, 
                searchable: false,
                render: function(data, type, row) {
                    return '<input type="checkbox" class="select-checkbox" value="' + row.DT_RowId + '">';
                },
                className: 'select-checkbox'
            },
            { data: 'name', name: 'name' },
            { data: 'created_at', name: 'created_at' },
            {
                data: 'id',
                name: 'actions',
                orderable: false,
                searchable: false,
                render: function(data, type, row, meta) {
                    return data; 
                }
            }
        ],
        order: [[1, 'asc']], 
        select: {
            style: 'multi',
            selector: 'td:first-child'
        },
        dom: 'Bfrtilp',
        buttons: [
            { extend: 'csv' },
            { extend: 'pdf' },
            { extend: 'excel', className: 'excelButton' },
            
        ],
    });

    if (table !== null) {
        table.destroy();
    }


    // Click event handler for delete button
    $('#delete-button').on('click', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        var selectedRows = table.rows('.selected').data().toArray();
        if (selectedRows.length > 0) {
            var software_ids = selectedRows.map(row => row.DT_RowId);
            $.ajax({
                url: "/admin/destroy_multiple_softwares",
                type: 'POST',
                data: { software_ids: software_ids },
                success: function(response) {
                    table.ajax.reload();
                },
                error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                    console.error('Error:', error);
                }
            });
        }
    });
});


Are there any console errors?
